# $C$-embedded and zero-set

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

we shall say that a subspace $S$ of $X$ is $C$-embedded ($C^{*}$-embedded) in $X$ if every function in $C(S)$ ($ C^{*}(S) $) can be extended to a function in $C(X)$($C^{*}(X)$).

Zero - set means:

> $ Z ( f ) =  f^{-1 } ( \{ 0 \} ) = \{ x \in X \vert f ( x ) = 0 \}$

**My questions:**

1:
let  $S \subset X $, if  every zero-set  in $S$ is a zero-set in $X$ , **is  $S$,   $C^{*}$-embedded in $X$?**

2: A discrete zero-set is $C^{*}$-embedded  **if and only  if** all of its subsets are zero-sets?

Comment: By "zero set", do you mean $Z(f)$ *for some* function $f$? Otherwise, for your two questions, I have to ask "zero set of what function".

Comment: @PaulSinclair common usage is zero-set of some continuous function.